# Code split/format for press - need authoritative mention

Tags: java, c++, python, ruby, formatting

I'm looking for fast and efficent way to split code and prapare it for press. I'm working for coder magazine, and it's always a huge problem to prepare code for press, 'cause  space in one column is limited. Now I'm doing it manually and it is very tiresome. Let me give you an example. This is a code I'm working on right now (already formatted/spitted in my own style), it's for Android:

```
private void GetFiles() {
  listBox1.Items.Clear();
  var storeFile = IsolatedStorageFile. 
    GetUserStoreForApplication();
  string fileString = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("*");
  string[] files = storeFile.GetFileNames("*");
  for (int i = 0; i < storeFile.GetFileNames("/" + 
      fileString).Length; i++) {
    String fileName = storeFile.GetFileNames(fileString)[i];
    String ext = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 3);
    if (ext == "png") listBox1.Items.Add(fileName);
```

}
}

Note that

```
var storeFile = IsolatedStorageFile. 
    GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

is one line. It's just too long for press column, that's why I split by the nearest logical break (here - point) and indent the second part of the line with 4 spaces (inline is always indented by 2 spaces). I know, it's not the best way, it's hard to understand. That's why I'm looking an authoritative answer from the wide range of software developers. I have to work not only with C++ code, but with Assembler, JavaScript, Ruby and Python. The last one is a separate problem - it's indent-dependive, so I have to be especially carefull with indents.

**So, the question is:** which is the best way to format code in limited space of the magazine? Which way do **you** prefer? Please, suggest your own ideas. Every answer is highly appreciated.

**UPD**: Here's the way how it looks in magazine now: [image: Current look]. It may help you to uderstand the problem. Too long lines are splited by '\' and the last part of line is indented. Not too obvious, isn't it? =(

Comment: Just to get response from wide rage of developers. This is a code for android platforms, right now I'm working on it. I'd like to get ideas from every programmer. I do hope response from real software engeneers will help us to make code in magazine way more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use Eclipse built-in code formatter. You can easily configure the maxline length amongst other things. Then you simply use ctrl+shift+f to format according to your defined codestyle.

Ah, I didn't realize this wasn't a specific Java question. The code you pasted here doesn't compile and the editor refuses to format it. But if I use your screenshot it will, by default look like this (i changed max line length a bit tho):

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
    Vector3 prosition = new Vector3(
        tranform.position.x,
        transform.position.y + 1,
        transform.position.z);
    }
    Instantiate(ProjectilePrefab, position,
            Quaternion.Identiy);
}
```

Comment: Wovw, it's a great sulution. I definatelly should try. And how will it split code lines like ListBoxItem selectedItem = this.listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.listBox1.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem; ?

Comment: Good idea - code formatting is hard to automate, and existing tools have had a lot of effort poured into them

Answer (score 1):

So...  in this loop you want to retrieve a full file listing, test the length, then get the full file listing again (except slightly different because you left out the `"/"` prefix) and hope that there is still an `i`th element.  You repeat the process as many times as there are files, to achieve the delicious time complexity of `O(2n^2)`.

You are of course publishing this function as an example of what NOT to do, right?

To give my preference on layout, I'd rather you split at the `=` if it fits...  But now that you've edited with a sample image it looks like you have even less space to play with than you first hinted.

If you were actually trying to publish a less expensive algorithm, you might choose to store the resulting search in a variable, and shorten most of the lines in that loop...